# Fixed effects in Stata

Tags: stata

Very new to Stata, so struggling a bit with using fixed effects.  The data here is made up, but bear with me.  I have a bunch of dummy variables that I am doing regression with.  My dependent variable is a dummy that is 1 if a customer bought something and 0 if not.  My fixed effects are whether or not there was a yellow sign out front or not (dummy variable again).  My independent variable is if the store manager said hi or not (dummy variable).

Basically, I want my output to look like this (with standard errors obviously)

```
                        Yellow sign       No Yellow sign
Manager said hi          estimate            estimate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `##` operator in a regression to get a saturated model with fixed effects:

First, input data such that you have a binary outcome (*bought*), a dependent variable (*saidhi*), and a fixed effects variable (*sign*). *saidhi* should be correlated with your outcome (so there is a portion of *saidhi* that is uncorrelated with *bought* and a portion that is), and your FE variable should be correlated with both *bought* and *saidhi* (otherwise there is no point having it in your regression if you are only interested in the effect of *saidhi*).

```
clear
set obs 100
set seed 45
gen bought = runiform() > 0.5                               // Binary y, 50/50 probability
gen saidhi = runiform() + runiform()^2*bought               
gen sign = runiform() + runiform()*saidhi + runiform()*bought > 0.66666 // Binary FE, correlated with both x and y 
replace saidhi = saidhi > 0.5
```

Now, run your regression:

```
* y = x + FE + x*FE + cons
reg bought saidhi##sign, r


exit
```

Your output should be:

```
Linear regression                               Number of obs     =        100
                                                F(3, 96)          =      13.34
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.1703
                                                Root MSE          =     .46447

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      bought |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    1.saidhi |   .3571429   .2034162     1.76   0.082    -.0466351    .7609209
      1.sign |   .3869048   .1253409     3.09   0.003      .138105    .6357046
             |
 saidhi#sign |
        1 1  |  -.1427489   .2373253    -0.60   0.549    -.6138359    .3283381
             |
       _cons |   .0714286   .0702496     1.02   0.312    -.0680158     .210873
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*1.saidhi* is the effect of *saidhi* when `sign == 0`. *1.sign* is the effect of the sign, alone, i.e. when `saidhi == 0`. The parts under `saidhi#sign` describe the interaction between these two variables (i.e. the marginal effect of them both being 1 at the same time... keep in mind the total effect of them both being one includes the previous two terms). Your constant is represents the average value of *bought* when both are 0 (e.g. this as the same as you would get from `sum bought if saidhi == 0 & sign == 0`).